# WAN friendly remote registry reads

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have a .NET app that does the following:

1. Connect to a remote machine with the StdRegProv class from WMI.
2. Query a subkey for all of its sub keys.
3. In each of those sub keys (about 60 or so sub keys), download all
   of the registry values (about 10 or so values).

Over a WAN with a 1.5 Mbps link, it takes about a minute to download the contents of each sub key in step #3... so the whole process finishes in about a hour.

I have a feeling if I did one bulk download of all sub keys and contents, this process would take much less than a hour, but I can't find any API for this.

Does anyone know of a better way to download lots of registry values over a WAN? I'll be testing this with the Remote Registry Service as well, but the APIs look similar to WMI's StdRegProv, so I'm not sure if its going to be any better.

Comment: Do you compress the data before sending it down the wire?

Comment: Of course he doesn't do wire compression, he's using a DCOM RPC.

Answer (score 0):

One of the requirements is to not have any third-party software on the remote machine. I'm limited to native Windows technologies (e.g. WMI, Remote Registry Service, etc.). That also means I have no control over compression.

Answer (score -1):

Write yourself a proxy service and roll it out with a policy

Comment: Remote reads are slow because they produce a lot of chatter, which is fine on a low latency connection like a LAN but problematic on a WAN. Solution: don't do remote reads. Get a proxy service to do local reads on your behalf. A proxy is something that acts on behalf of something else. Or did you think proxy=web? In addition to suggesting a high performance solution I also suggested a way to roll it out to the target machines. The fact that Shannon can't *use* this approach takes nothing away from the usefulness of the suggestion.

Comment: It was possible to answer my question without being condescending.  Thank you, I know what a proxy is.